# How to move large react + webpack application to next js for SEO

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I have a large react + webpack application with all the compilers and chunks configuration.

when I deployed the app on production, Google crawler bots are not able to crawl, I wanted to know the fastest way to convert my application from reactJS to nextJS,

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Muhammad Owais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9313844/muhammad-owais) did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Questions that are open:

- On which basis did you create your ReactJS app ? If it is create-react-app then:
  https://www.pheuberger.com/convert-create-react-app-to-nextjs/

---

It is not correct that client side ReactJS apps are not crawled by Google Bots.

Google Bots have more than 250 criterias to crawl websites and they also execute Javascript.

It is useful to have a look at your javascript execution time, file size and the most important thing: **Your links/navigation !**

Please take into consideration to push the **browser history**, otherwise it will be impossible to have your page crawled correctly by Google Bots.

The mechanism of Server Side Rendering (SSR) is a completely different than having a client side rendering ReactJS app.

Regarding NextJs:

1. You can use exportPathMap to pregenerate the pages and upload them to a webspace for instance
2. You can use Server Side Rendering (SSR) - then you will need a NodeJS on a (Virtual) Server (caution: a normal webspace usually dooes not have a virtual server with NodeJs).